# how to refer to the actual object and not all objects

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck using the this keyword.How to refer to the single object that is being clicked and not to the entire this.categories

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class PortfolioGallery{

    constructor(){

        this.categories=$(".our-work-nav_categories a");
        this.gallery=$('.our-work-gallery_photo');

        this.properties={
            "color":"red",
            "font-weight":"900"
        };
        this.resetCss={
            "color":"",
            "font-weight":""
        };
        this.categories.first().css(this.properties);
        this.events();
    }

    events(){
        this.categories.click(this.filterCategories.bind(this));
        console.log(this);
    }

    filterCategories(){
        var cssP={
            "color":"yellow"
        };
        this.categories.bind(this).css({
            "display":"none"
        });

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `this.categories.click` to `this.click`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information its hard to know exactly what you're looking for. However I will try to explain what I think you're looking for.

Lets start with a simple example

```
Class MyClass{
     constructor(value1,value2){
        this.name = value1;
        this.lastName = value2;
   }
     getName(){
     return this.name;
  }
}
```

To use this code you would create and object and would be able to to use the methods of this class on these objects.

```
var testClass = new MyClass("name","last name");
var myName = testClass.getName(); 
var myNameAnotherWay = testClass.name; //another way to set the value of testClass.name to a variable.
```

This would set the 'myName' or 'myNameAnotherWay' variable to the name value of the testClass object.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear.What I am trying to achieve is that I want to change the styling of the link elements when they get clicked on one per time.In this case this.categories points to all links 

I am trying to do it using this and bind.

Comment: <nav class="our-work-nav_categories">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">BRANDING</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">WEB DESIGN</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">MOBILE UI</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">ILLUSTRATIONS</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
 }